# Как правильно пишется «не( )правильно»?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: «неправильно» или «не правильно»?

Comment: Используются обе формы, надо ток правильно выбрать. Например:  (1) Но и принижать их роль было бы неправильно.   (2) Надо идти. Не пойдете, будет плохо, не правильно. Все решат, что вы терзаетесь чувством вины, а значит, вы виноваты.  Читайте: § 61. Частица не с наречиями  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81

Comment: Этот вопрос  слишком общего характера, практически автор просит нас пересказать содержание справочника Розенталя.  Вопросы должны быть конкретными, в них следует обозначить проблему, которую автор не  смог решить самостоятельно с помощью правил из этого справочника.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Неправильно» в разных случаях может быть как наречием, так и кратким прилагательным. Чтобы определить это, нужно посмотреть, на какой вопрос оно отвечает, и к какому слову относится.

С глаголами все понятно: с частицей «не» они пишутся раздельно, а вот наречия и прилагательные употребляются по-разному в зависимости от ситуации.

**Рассмотрим несколько примеров.**

Сначала стоит проверить, **употребляется ли данное слово без приставки «не».**

«Нечаянно», «нелепо», например, всегда пишутся слитно, потому что в современном языке нет слов «чаянно» и «лепо».

Слово «правильно» существует, поэтому с ним всё немного сложнее. Посмотрите, **можно ли** слово **заменить** в предложении его **синонимом**. В этом случае **написание будет слитным.**

*«Твое высказывание неправильно»* (Равнозначно: *«Твое высказывание ошибочно»*.)

**Если** в предложении **есть противопоставление**, **то «не» – частица, нужно писать раздельно.**

*«Информация дана не правильно, а искаженно».*

Правило применимо, **даже когда противопоставление** не прописано, но **подразумевается**:

*― Я поступил правильно.*

*― Нет, не правильно!* («...а плохо, нечестно» – можно продолжить по смыслу.)

*«Хоть и неправильно вы всё написали, а так старательно! Хорошо, повышу вам оценку на балл»*. Это **не противопоставление**, союз «а» можно заменить на союз «зато», слово **пишется слитно**.

**«Не правильно» нужно писать раздельно, если это сочетание стоит после усиливающих слов: совсем, вовсе, нисколько, ничуть, далеко и так далее.**

*«Но расположение на карте указано вовсе не правильно».*

*«Ты вообще не правильно перевела эту фразу».*

Однако исключения есть всегда, особенно это касается кратких прилагательных с наречиями «совсем» и «вовсе».

Заметьте, кто-нибудь произносит с досадой: *«Все как-то совсем неправильно...»* – ударение на «совсем», имеется в виду «очень неправильно, плохо, сумбурно».

«Совсем» относится не к слову «правильно», не отрицает его в отдельности, а усиливает сочетание «(не)правильно» целиком.

Подсказкой может служить то, что в этом предложении сложно заменить по смыслу «совсем» на «нисколько» или «отнюдь». Но чаще всего приведенных выше правил бывает достаточно.

[Как правильно пишется «неправильно»?](https://uchipravila.ru/orfografiya/nepravilno)